# Linking Java with C++ statically using JNI

Tags: java, c++, java-native-interface

Is it possible to link a C++ library to a Java program statically, in a way that will make them into a single file ,just like linking 2 C++ libraries?
(I read that java programs can also be compiled to EXE).

Comment: Under normal circumstances I'd have to say no. Microsoft use dirty hacks to make "mixed assemblies" containing with managed an unmanaged code, and possibly there exists a java->exe tool which does the same. I'm curious as to why a DLL isn't suitable, though.

Comment: because of this :)
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11018263/my-java-gui-interfaces-with-my-uber-cool-proprietary-dll-how-can-i-prevent-3rd

Comment: Oh dear. I would suggest that what you really want to do is to run your application as a service accessible over the internet, then. Failing that, you should probably save up a bit and have a chat with the Excelsior JET guys, who seem to be the most likely people to support this sort of functionality.

Comment: @Rook - mixed mode assemblies aren't exactly dirty hacks. They're quite well documented/normal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Theoretically this should be possible to create one EXE that already includes the required JNI functions used by the JVM.

This EXE would have to load the Java part by starting a JVM instance in the same process (by loading jvm.dll and executing it as shown in question [JNI Java in c++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1912962/jni-java-in-c)).

The Java-EXE-wrapper I know do not support something like this as they come with a pre-compiled EXE that gets the used JAR attached as resource. Therefore I assume you would have to build you own C/C++ executable and implement all the functionality you need.

Comment: No. Loading jvm.dll doesn't qualify as 'just like linking 2 C++ libraries'.

Comment: @EJP Of course the JVM can never be compiled into the EXE but the used library that should be used together with can be linked into the resulting executable. Then you would have one EXE file that includes everything except the JRE.

Comment: He specifically asked for a single file. This is at least two files.

Comment: The original question is only asking if it is possible to integrate a C++ library. The JVM is not a C++ library there out of scope of this question. Hence my answer is correct. You are thinking way too far.

Comment: @EJP: When I wrote "a single file", I meant that I'd like my C++ library to be integrated into the Java EXE. Having JVM as a seperate DLL is prefectly fine :)

Comment: @Robert: So, what you're saying is that my process should be a C++ process, which will activate the java part?

Comment: @Idov: Yes that is what I was proposing. You can even call back C functions from within Java via JNI.

Comment: @Robert: Wait, will I be able to call from Java C++ functions which reside in the EXE itself?

Comment: @Idov: Not every method, only those that are created via JNI. I never tried it but generally it should be possible. It doesn't matter if the function is implemented in a loaded DLL or the main EXE itself. It just have to be present at runtime.

Comment: @leov So by 'integrated into the Java EXE' you also mean '*not* integrated into the Java EXE'. You can see the confusion you're causing.

Answer (score 0):

When I use JNI I include the dll with JNI support into my jar file. Then access it by classpath. You will have single jar file.

Comment: Really? How can the operating system load a DLL in a JAR file? And how is this 'just like linking 2 C++ libraries'?

Answer (score 0):

It isn't possible unless you have access to a static version of the jvm.lib library. It is distributed as a dynamic-link library referring to jvm.dll. You can't do this.